# BMO space and representation theory

Tags: soft-question, finite-groups, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Does the [BMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation#The_John%E2%80%93Nirenberg_Inequality) function have any applications in representation theory? Thanks!